# Running CodedUI tests on VM having test Agent installed,but TestCases are getting failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I configured the test agent on VM, but when initiate a test from MTM/TFS build, the test agent is not performing the GUI test. i can see a successful call from the test controller to the VM test agent. The VM is not lock and in active window screen but somehow its not performing the GUI action that i coded. it threw below exception after test failed:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
>   The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details: TechnologyName: 'MSAA'ControlType:"
>   followed by exception thrown from TestCleanup "DB File can not be
>   access as it is being used by another process

This is very common exception where cannot find the control, but the control is on the screen. the script is running fine on local system and some other Testcases are getting passed on VMS so there is no problem with testscript,testcontroller and tfs build. Is there any missing config or permission on my VM? or VM do not have mouse/keyboard causing the GUI test failure?

Comment: Only GUI test failed, others run successfully ? What's the result if you manually run(not through TFS build) the GUI test on the VM agent? This will narrow down if the issue is related your environment/ setting on VM or TFS related.

Comment: Yes,Failure are related to GUI only.Manually also those TC are getting passed

Comment: Did you configure the test agent to [**run as interact process**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332(v=vs.120).aspx)? It's necessary when you want to run automated tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up your agent to run as a process instead of a service.  And what's the version of TFS are you using? Which build are you running XAML or vNext?

Comment: Test Agent is configured as Interactive process and I am using XAML builds. I am using  visual studio 2013

Comment: Could you try to deploy/configure the test agent on a normal OS or Server environment  with the same settings/environment. If it's also failed with the same error, afraid it's related to your tfs build process or definition setting. Moreover, according to the error info `DB File can not be access as it is being used by another process`  Any process in  task manager may cause the issue? End the related process, try it again.